# Do I have to specify type variance in subtypes?

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a trait

```
sealed trait Expr[-InT, +OutT] {
  def apply(lhs: InT): OutT
}
```

I want to create a subtype `And` contravariant in `InT`. Do I have to implement it as this (1):

```
type BExpr[-InT] = Expr[InT, Boolean]

final case class And[-InT](exp: BExpr[InT], exps: BExpr[InT]*) extends BExpr[InT] {
  def apply(lhs: InT) = exps.foldLeft(exp.apply(lhs))(_ & _(lhs))
}
```

Or is the following enough (2)?

```
type BExpr[InT] = Expr[InT, Boolean]

final case class And[InT](exp: BExpr[InT], exps: BExpr[InT]*) extends BExpr[InT] {
  def apply(lhs: InT) = exps.foldLeft(exp.apply(lhs))(_ & _(lhs))
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that you need to add variants to subtypes as well.Variants specify the correlation between subtypes and supertypes.

Comment: I thought as well. But both syntaxes are apparently valid, so I am confused.

Comment: Both syntaxes will be valid.But making the subtype as [-Int],will make it invariant for its subclasses.

Comment: Does this mean it is superfluous as the class is `final`?

Comment: Yes I think as the class in final.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let's do a little test.

```
scala> trait A[+T]
defined trait A

scala> trait B[T] extends A[T]
defined trait B

scala> def b1: B[String] = ???
b1: B[String]

scala> def b2: B[AnyRef] = b1
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : B[String]
 required: B[AnyRef]
Note: String <: AnyRef, but trait B is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
       def b2: B[AnyRef] = b1
                           ^

scala> def a: A[AnyRef] = b1
a: A[AnyRef]

scala> trait B[+T] extends A[T]
defined trait B

scala> def b3: B[String] = ???
b3: B[String]

scala> def b4: B[AnyRef] = b3
b4: B[AnyRef]
```

So yes it does make a difference. If you want to expose your subtype to the world, not make it a private internal implementation, it's probably better to add the proper variance annotations.